# Let a click on a FlowPanel propagate to element sitting below it?

Tags: gwt

I have a Canvas element, and a FlowPanel on top of it (in z order). When I click on the FlowPanel, it seems to intercept the click and stops propagating it. I don't have any click listeners set on it though. I want the canvas below it to receive the click event.

Is there a way to get the FlowPanel to ignore the click and let it propagate to the canvas that sits below it?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements/4839672#4839672

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome, Firefox and Safari 4+ you can use the [`pointer-events` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) (it's also [well-supported](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) by mobile browsers), but for other browsers (IE, Opera and older Safaris) you'll have to listen to click events at the `FlowPanel` level and fire synthetic click events on the canvas.
Assuming the `FlowPanel` and the canvas are aligned, at the same position, you should be able to use [`DomEvent.fireNativeEvent`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/DomEvent.html#fireNativeEvent%28com.google.gwt.dom.client.NativeEvent,%20com.google.gwt.event.shared.HasHandlers%29) coupled with [`Document.get().createClickEvent`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Document.html#createClickEvent%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29).